# Combine array of objects into a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have data that looks like this.

```
[
  {
    key: 'myKey'
    value: 'myValue'
  },
  {
    key: 'mySecondKey'
    value: 'mySecondValue'
  },
  {
    key: 'myThirdKey'
    value: 'myThirdValue'
  },
]
```

The amount of objects varies depending on how much values an account has set. I'm trying to return this in a format that looks like this

```
{
  mykey: 'myValue'
  mySecondKey: 'mySecondValue'
  myThirdkey: 'myThirdValue'
}
```

Any advice on how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something, like

```js
const src = [{key:'myKey',value:'myValue'},{key:'mySecondKey',value:'mySecondValue'},{key:'myThirdKey',value:'myThirdValue'},],

    result = Object.assign({}, ...src.map(o => ({[o.key]: o.value})))
    
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for this:

```js
const data = [{key:"myKey",value:"myValue"},{key:"mySecondKey",value:"mySecondValue"},{key:"myThirdKey",value:"myThirdValue"}];

const res = data.reduce((obj, {key, value}) => ({...obj, [key]: value}), {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers work but I feel like they are a bit complicated, here's a simple for of loop:

```js
const data = [
  {
    key: 'myKey',
    value: 'myValue'
  },
  {
    key: 'mySecondKey',
    value: 'mySecondValue'
  },
  {
    key: 'myThirdKey',
    value: 'myThirdValue'
  }
];

const result = {};

for(const {key, value} of data) {
  result[key] = value;
}

console.log(result);
```